# Error while incrementing date with 1 month

Tags: php, datetime

I am facing a strange issue with incrementing date with one month for following case
For date input as `2014-01-31` I am getting `2014-03-03` while it should "2014-02-28"

I am using following code

```
$time = strtotime("2014-01-31");
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
```

Comment: There's also an answer to a quite similar question that I posted a few months ago - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19719945/368896

Comment: because in the month of feb their is 28 days. so it will skip to next month which is 3 mar.

Answer (score 3):

The +1 month in php has unexpected behaviour when you use it at the 30th or 31st of January. You will get a date in March. This is because php online raises the month number by 1 (so 2014-01-31 will become 2014-02-31. This doesn't exist so php will correct this into 2012-02-28 + 3.

This will get you the right result at the end of the month.

```
$d = new DateTime( '2014-01-31' );
$d->modify( 'last day of +1 month' );
$final = $d->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```

This is explained at the php manual at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#107331